# Ant change directory structure in the war file

Tags: ant, war, build.xml

I'm new to ant and I have to wrap my web project in war file and I'm using ant
My project is structured like that:

> myproject
>   --images
>   --css
>   --js

and in the war file the final structure is like:

> myproject
>   --css
>   --images
>   --js
>   --META-INF
>   --WEB-INF

I'd like  to change the final structure (to put everything from the project directory in "public" folder) BUT only in the war file, and I'd like to be like that:

> myproject
>   --public
>   -----css
>   -----images
>   -----js
>   --META-INF
>   --WEB-INF

I have try using copy task and move task but with no success...
What should i do in order to accomplish this?

Comment: can you show the current script?

Comment: Hi Rao so far it is like this https://jsfiddle.net/n6n6b8h4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using `prefix` attribute in a `zipfileset` may help you (see [zipfileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html)):

```
<target name="Wrappin the in war file" description="Compiling....">
    <mkdir dir="${build-directory}" />
    <delete file="${build-directory}/${war-file-name}" />
    <war warfile="${build-directory}/${war-file-name}" webxml="${web-xml-file}">
        <zipfileset dir="${web-directory}" prefix="public">
            <exclude name=".git/**" />
            <exclude name=".svn/**" />
            <exclude name=".idea/**" />
            <exclude name="node_modules/**" />
            <exclude name="bower_components/**" />
        </zipfileset>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Built-By" value="${builder}" />
            <attribute name="Built-On" value="${build-info.current-date}" />
            <attribute name="Built-At" value="${build-info.current-time}" />
        </manifest>
    </war>
</target>
```